# How can I efficiently mask out certain pairs in (2, N) tensor?

Tags: numpy, pytorch, torch, pytorch-geometric

I have a torch tensor `edge_index` of shape `(2, N)` that represents edges in a graph. For each `(x, y)` there is also a `(y, x)`, where `x` and `y` are node IDs (ints). During the forward pass of my model I need to mask out certain edges. So, for example, I have:

```
n1 = [0, 3, 4]   # list of node ids as x
n2 = [1, 2, 1]   # list of node ids as y
edge_index = [[1, 2, 0, 1, 3, 4, 2, 3, 1, 4, 2, 4],  # actual edges as (x, y) and (y, x)
              [2, 1, 1, 0, 4, 3, 3, 2, 4, 1, 4, 2]]

# do something that efficiently removes (x, y) and (y, x) edges as formed by n1 and n2
```

Final edge_index should look like:

```
>>> edge_index
[[1, 2, 3, 4, 2, 4],
 [2, 1, 4, 3, 4, 2]]
```

Preferably we need to efficiently make some kind of boolean mask that I can apply to edge index e.g. as `edge_index[:, mask]` or something like that.

Could also be done in numpy but I'd like to avoid converting back and forth.

Edit #1:

If that can't be done, then I can think of a way so that, instead of n1 and n2, I have access to the indices of the positions I need to exclude in one tensor e.g. `_except=[2, 3, 6, 7, 8, 9]` (by making a dict/index once in the beginning).

Is there a way to get the desired result by "telling" `edge_index` to drop the indices in `except`? `edge_index[:, _except]` gives me the ones I want to get rid of. I need its complement operation.

Edit #2:

I managed to do it like this:

```
mask = torch.ones(edge_index.shape[1], dtype=torch.bool)
for i in range(len(n1)):
    mask = mask &  ~(torch.tensor([n1[i], n2[i]], dtype=torch.long) == edge_index.T).all(dim=1) & ~(torch.tensor([n2[i], n1[i]], dtype=torch.long) == edge_index.T).all(dim=1)

edge_index[:, mask]
```

but it is too slow and I can't use it. How can I speed it up?

Edit #3: I managed to solve this Edit#1 efficiently with:

```
mask = torch.ones(edge_index.shape[1], dtype=torch.bool)
mask[_except] = False
edge_index[:, mask]
```

Still interested in solving the original problem if someone comes up with something...

Answer (score 1):

If you're ok with the way you suggested at Edit#1,

you get the complement result by:

`edge_index[:, [i for i in range(edge_index.shape[1]) if not (i in _except)]]`

hope this is fast enough for your requirement.

---

Edit 1:

```
from functools import reduce

ids = torch.stack([torch.tensor(n1), torch.tensor(n2)], dim=1)
ids = torch.cat([ids, ids[:, [1,0]]], dim=0)
res = edge_index.unsqueeze(0).repeat(6, 1, 1) == ids.unsqueeze(2).repeat(1, 1, 12)
mask = ~reduce(lambda x, y: x | (reduce(lambda p, q: p & q, y)), res, reduce(lambda p, q: p & q, res[0]))
edge_index[:, mask]
```

---

Edit 2:

```
ids = torch.stack([torch.tensor(n1), torch.tensor(n2)], dim=1)
ids = torch.cat([ids, ids[:, [1,0]]], dim=0)
res = edge_index.unsqueeze(0).repeat(6, 1, 1) == ids.unsqueeze(2).repeat(1, 1, 12)
mask = ~(res.sum(1) // 2).sum(0).bool()
edge_index[:, mask]
```

Comment: I found a non for-loopy way to do this. I do:

```
mask = torch.ones(edge_index.shape[1], dtype=torch.bool)
mask[_except] = False
edge_index[:, _except]
```

and it works reasonably fast but it requires a pandas MultiIndex to get the position. I am still waiting for if someone can solve the original problem.

Comment: Can you check if the updated code fits your problem?

Comment: @Michael I added another code without using `reduce`

Comment: It gives me a shape related error during the `res = ...` step. What are you trying to do here?

Comment: I omitted a single line, now fixed it. Can you check again? I'd expanded given `edge_index` tensor and compared to the tensor composed with `n1` and `n2` to generate a mask tensor, which is used to mask `edge_index` by `edge_index[:, mask]`

Comment: It does seem to work on this example although what must `6` and `12` be in general? Say if `k=len(n1)=len(n2)` and `w=len(edge_index)`. Is `6 == 2*k` and `12 == w`?

Comment: I just tried it on my project and I realised I should have mentioned that `edge_index` is kinda huge. This runs out of memory as it tries to allocate 22.5 GBs of RAM for `edge_index.unsqueeze(0).repeat(*, 1, 1)`...

Comment: Yep, you're right for `6` and `12`. With that huge `edge_index`, I doubt there is a solution that doesn't use a loop. 

Comment: You re probably right. Edit #1 works for now. Thank you for your input!